# MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a problem with my code I used this code in 
app.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const dotenv = require('dotenv'); 
dotenv.config()

  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL) 
.then(() => console.log("DB connected!"));

    mongoose.connection.on('error',function(err){   
console.log("The error is: ");
});
```

env.txt:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb+srv://blur:blur@nodeapi-pfnvf8.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
PORT:8080
```

and for some reason it's giving me this weird error:

```
throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
    ^ MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at new MongooseError (C:\Users\razei\Desktop\Recat\project2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\mongooseError.js:14:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\razei\Desktop\Recat\project2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:465:11)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\razei\Desktop\Recat\project2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:289:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\razei\Desktop\Recat\project2\ap.js:9:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

can someone please help me I read a few posts but none of them helped

Comment: So maybe `process.env.MONGO_URL` is not string?

Comment: @Justinas Ofcurse it's a string why wouldn't it be

Comment: Because error states directly to that function call: `Make sure the first parameter to mongoose.connect() or mongoose.createConnection() is a string`

Comment: @Justinas you are right when i changed it to: mongodb+srv://blur:blur@nodeapi-pfnvf8.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true it did work

Comment: @Justinas But I saw a video where he did it like i did and it did work for him

Comment: Forgot to load this env file? Some caching? Not reloading properly?

Comment: @Justinas It's not recognizing dotenv for some reason it's like it doesn't exist and yes i did do npm i dotenv

Comment: Maybe because `dotenv` looks for `.env`, but you have `.txt`?

Comment: @Justinas what do you mean yeah my file is .env.txt what do i need to change it to?

Comment: @Justinas never mind, I did put it as a env file http://prntscr.com/nqibqs

Answer (score 12):

This also occurs when you aren't saving your .env file in the root folder.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasted 4 hours just to copy-paste this file

Answer (score 3):

Save your env file as .env not env.txt and make sure it's in your root folder as well & see if that works! Also MONGO_URI is the traditional naming convention but that shouldn't matter.

```
mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to Mongo!');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error connecting to Mongo', err);
    });
```

Additionally you can simplify your 2 require statements above with the lines below and you should call this as soon as possible:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

Answer (score 1):

Require dotenv like this. It worked for me

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, the env file should be saved as .env not env.txt, .txt is an extension for text files.

Also, I don't think you have named your project 'test' so make sure to change it to your current project name.

If you still get an error, do not use environment variables instead add the whole mongodb path inside `mongoose.connect()` in double or single quotes.

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.mongodb, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was getting the same errors, It was crashing due to the environment variable MONGODB_URI not being set and running heroku config returned with no variables in the cli.

The fix was running : heroku addons:create mongolab:sandbox

If heroku push origin master is needed, then heroku config should now show your .env variable.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error as well, The first thing you need to do is to place your  `.env` file in the "ROOT FOLDER". This will solve your issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error comes when we put our database credentials in .env file and in main file of server we create connection before .env file, instead we should create connection after requiring .env file.

Answer (score 0):

was having the same error.. :

This also worked for me..

require('dotenv').config();

checkout this post for more info : https://dev.to/aritik/connecting-to-mongodb-using-mongoose-3akh

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the root folder is where `config.env` is created and that the right path is specified for @ app.js => `dotenv.config(path: "./config.env")`.

```js
dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
    dotenv.config({path:'config.env'});

    const mongoose = require('mongoose');


    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true
    });
```

I fixed that [myApp.js file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRlwf.png)

[config.env file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6xwc.png)

package.json file

```
  "name": "fcc-mongo-mongoose-challenges",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A boilerplate project",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.12.4",
    "mongodb": "^4.12.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.15"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/boilerplate-mongomongoose.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "mongoose",
    "express"
  ],
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Please check above two screenshots to solve this problem
Hope this will be help to anyone

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33411334)