# Heroku deployment postbuild for project structure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

My MERN Project structure is:

```
MyProject:
-server.js
-client
--index.js
```

and postbuild script includes  "heroku-postbuild":"NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install cd client  && npm run build cd client"

but I am getting error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you run

```sh
heroku logs --tail
```

You'll most probably see the below error

```
Error: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` 
must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

This problem is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56202427/13842961) before.

The problem can be in your env file location or in your MONGO_URI given in your env file.

Or you can check for more solutions there.